# Sharepoint 2013 - How can I share a specific file?

Tags: 2013, document-library, permissions, share

I'm using Sharepoint 2013.

I have a sharepoint document library named "Cloud". Only the Administrator has permissions to access this site. Now I have 2 folders and 2 Files. I only want to share the file "KUEBA_Background".

[image: 2 Files]

Then I mark the file, click on "share", and enter the username and share the file.

[image]

Then I receive the Email with the share notification. When i click on it, the 
file opens. 
BUT i can't access the sharepoint site. I want to access the site and only see this one file. When I access it, the error: "Sorry, this list has not been released for you" popps up.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint it is not possible to Share only one file and Access SharePoint site.What happen when you give permission to one item then SharePoint automatically give "Limited Access" to this user in whole site.but it does not mean that you can open site and access file from there.SharePoint handle security very well. You need to **view** permission on whole site for access through site.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't think this is true, because i saw a post (in german) on this link: http://bpio.co/2013/06/20/vor-und-nachteile-der-sharefreigeben-funktion-in-sharepoint-2013/
He describes how to share the single file, but he doesn't go through all steps. When I try it like him, it doesn't work. So maybe one of you has done it before and can tell me, how it's gonna work out.

Comment: I think you will need to give view permission on library. So you can access library.

Comment: Sam is right. This is how SharePoint works. If you share a file and assign the user direct permissions on the file, the user will not receive permissions to view the site or the library. If you share by assigning the user to a group then the user will have all the rights the group has. This is also explained in the german post (if chrome translation is right :))

Comment: @Suleyman: In his post he says the following (translated to english): If he trys now to manipulate the site, he can see the site and the library, but only the single shared document. (Sollte er nun versuchen die URL zur Website zu manipulieren, sieht er zwar die Seite und die Bibliothek, aber nur das eine Element.)
It works somehow (because he already made it), so again, can someone tell me how this works?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the anwser. You have to deactivate the Feature "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode" to access the site and see the documents tab, but not the files. (Microsoft Link: https://support.microsoft.com/de-ch/help/3039997/users-can-t-access-a-shared-folder-in-sharepoint-online)

Then you can share a single file. Now you can access the site and only see the single file.